# При изменении переменной во вложенном классе она становится равная null

Tags: java, android, javamail

В классе GetInboxMails я изменяю переменную messages и потом в классе FragmentInbox она уже становиться равной null.

```
public class FragmentInbox extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<Message> messages;

    GetInboxMails getInboxMails = new GetInboxMails();
    getInboxMails.execute();
    try {
        Log.i("EmailClient", "В listView.setAdapter будет передана переменная message, равная: " + messages); //////здесь messages = null
        listView.setAdapter(new MailItemAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.show_email_list, R.id.mail_list, messages));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //showSingleEmail(getContext(), messages.get(position));
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("EmailClient", "Error in listView.setAdapter ", e);
    }

    return view;
}

public class GetInboxMails extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        WaitingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Reading data", "Fetching mails...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        WaitingDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(context, "To fetching is complite!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            Mail inbox = new Mail(user, password, host, port, auth);
            messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
            Message[] arrayMessage;
            arrayMessage = inbox.getMessages("INBOX");
            for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
                messages.add(arrayMessage[i]);
            Log.i("EmailClient", "Отработал метод doInBackground с переменными: " + user + " " + password + " " + host + " " + port + " " + auth + " " + messages);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("EmailClient", "Error fetching email in function doInBackground! ", e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Интересная история, хотя кода и многовато. А в чём состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: @VladD при изменении переменной messages в классе GetInboxMails потом в классе FragmentInbox она уже равна null. Проверено логами!

Comment: @VlaD, в классе FragmentInbox не могу использовать extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Boolean>, т.к. уже использую extends Fragment. Поэтому прошлось прибегнуть к созданию сложенного класса.

Comment: 1) Вопрос стоит поместить в сам вопрос (отредактируйте его), комментарии всё равно никто не читает. 2) Вы уверены, что весь этот код нужен, чтобы проиллюстрировать проблему? Чем больше кода, тем меньше шансов на ответ, тем более на хороший ответ.

Comment: @VladD, отредактировал

Answer (score 5):

Вы не понимаете как работает AsyncTask и многопоточность в целом. То что вы вызвали метод `execute()` не означает что `AsyncTask` полностью отработал. Это означает лишь то, что задача встала в очередь, а когда она до конца отработает не известно. Для таких ситуаций в `AsyncTask` существует метод `onPostExecute`, который вызывается гарантированно после метода `doInBackground()`, плюс ко всему он вызывается в UI потоке. Поэтому выполнять какие либо действия с `messages` нужно именно в этом методе. Т.е. код должен быть примерно таким.

```
public class FragmentInbox extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<Message> messages;


    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState {
        GetInboxMails getInboxMails = new GetInboxMails();
        getInboxMails.execute(); // на этом этапе messages еще не заполнена
        //остально код
        return view;
    }
}

    public class GetInboxMails extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            //здесь doInBackground уже отработал, messages заполнена

            listView.setAdapter(new MailItemAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.show_email_list, R.id.mail_list, messages));
            //остальной код
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // какой то код
        }
    }
}
```